# Connection between local freeness and the rank of matrices

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I am reading ch.16 of Eisenbud's Commutative Algebra, more precisely it's the very first paragraph of 16.7, where he wants to prove:

Suppose that $\mathcal{J}: R^t \longrightarrow R^r$ is a map of free modules over a ring $R$ whose rank is $\leqslant c $ and let $M= \textrm{coker}(\mathcal{J})$. Let $P$ be a prime ideal of $R$. We claim that $M_P$ is free of rank $r-c$ iff the matrix $\mathcal{J}$ taken modulo $P$ has rank exactly $c$.

The proof for $\Longrightarrow$ starts as follows:

We may assume that $R$ is local with maximal ideal $P$ to start with. Tensoring the sequence with $R/P$, we may assume that $R$ is a field. The rank of the vector space $M/PM$ is $r-c$ because $M$ was supposed free. It follows that the rank of the map $\mathcal{J} \otimes R/P$ is $c$.

It's clear for me that $M \otimes R/P \cong M/PM$.

My questions: In the proof, why may we assume the $R$ is local with maximal ideal $P$?

Which sequence is he tensoring?

And in the claim, why does he write: Suppose that $M$ is free instead of $M_{P}$?

I would be very glad if someone could help me.